# Oracle Apex while loop for inserting data

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am looking to insert a fairly large number of rows into a table to represent parking spaces in a lot. The table contains 3 fields, Parking_Space_ID, Space Status, and Zone_ID - which comes from 1 of 3 coloured zones. Each zone has 120, 120 and 300 spaces respectively.

I have attempted to create a while loop to insert the Zone_ID for each record, as the status can remain as its default value and the ID is auto generating:

```
DECLARE i int = 0
WHILE i < 120
BEGIN
    SET i = i + 1
    INSERT INTO tbl_Parking_Space (Zone_ID)
    VALUES (1)

    INSERT INTO tbl_Parking_Space (Zone_ID)
    VALUES (2)
END

SET i = 0
WHILE i < 300
BEGIN
    SET i = i + 1
    INSERT INTO tbl_Parking_Space (Zone_ID)
    VALUES (21)
END
```

On running this I am getting errors from line 1 and likely many more places, and I am not sure how to proceed with this. The current error I am getting is:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; not null range default character ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210100", line 669 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658 ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210100", line 655 ORA-06512: at "APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1855
```

Which unfortunately I am not sure how to deal with. Thank you in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you invent your own syntax if Oracle already did that for us, developers?

Here's code that compiles and *does something*. I have no idea if that's what you wanted, but - now that you have something to work with, feel free to improve it.

```
SQL> declare
  2    i int := 0;
  3  begin
  4    while i < 120 loop
  5      i := i + 1;
  6      insert into tbl_parking_space(zone_id)values(1);
  7      insert into tbl_parking_space(zone_id)values(2);
  8    end loop;
  9
 10    i := 0;
 11    while i < 300 loop
 12      i := i + 1;
 13      insert into tbl_parking_space(zone_id)values(21);
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from tbl_parking_space;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       540

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'm not as familiar as I thought I was with the oracle syntax

Comment: You're welcome. It'll be familiar to you if you use it more frequently :)